# What will happen if there's no constant $C$ such that $\lVert u\rVert_{L^p(M)}\leq C\lVert\Delta u\rVert_{L^p(M)}$ for each $u\in W_0^{2,p}$?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold with nontrivial boundary, $\Delta$ the $g$-Laplacian, and $W_0^{2,p}$ the functions in the Sobolev space $W^{2,p}$ that vanish on $\partial M$. I would like to know **if anything can be concluded if there's no constant $C$ such that
$$\lVert u\rVert_{L^p(M)}\leq C\lVert\Delta u\rVert_{L^p(M)}$$
for each $u\in W_0^{2,p}$.**

In fact, I was trying to prove **existence of a sequence of functions $u_i$ with $\lVert u_i\rVert_{L^p}=1$ and $\Delta u_i\to 0$ in $L^p$**. Thus far I haven't found a way, because I was expecting an inequality like
$$\lVert\Delta u\rVert_{L^p(M)}\leq C\lVert u\rVert_{L^p(M)}.$$
Is there any other thing I can do to prove the existence? Thank you.

Comment: Can you not construct a sequence as follows: let $w$ be harmonic in $M$ and not identically zero. Then let $u_i= w /\|w\|_{L^p(M)}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the answer. $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$, we can choose nonzero $w_k$ s.t. $\lVert w_k\rVert_{L^p(M)}>k\lVert\Delta w_k\rVert_{L^p(M)}$. Set each $u_k$ equal to $\frac{1}{\lVert w_k\rVert_p}w_k$. Then $\forall k\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$\lVert\Delta u_k-0\rVert_p<\frac{1}{k}.$$
Now let $k$ tend to infinity, and you will obtain the desired result.